# Magento 1.9 - Payment Gateway Success page empty or error

Tags: fatal-error, magento1.9.2.3, order-success-page

**Error : PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on boolean in /home/error/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Helper/Data.php on line 119**

I am using Paytm & Payubiz payment gateway for my Magento 1.9 website, from the day before to still now most of the customer said amount debited but success page is empty

One of the customers share the error screenshot:

[image]

Note : I spoke to Payment Gateway developer regarding this issue they told, our end everything ok, pls check your code. **Log error also not related to this error**

How to solve success page return error?

Comment: Check the Log file is there anything? check on extension where you call getMethodInstace() in that?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya I searched keyword getMethodInstace() with my paytm module doesn't match.

Comment: Used Paytm module https://we.tl/t-ForNRl1QSP

Comment: As you know i am using paytm & Payubiz, payubiz return Fatal error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on boolean in /home/test/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Observer.php on line 46

Answer (score 0):

Your helper is not working correctly and success page try to call helper method.

It have 2 solution as below:

1. try to find issue why helper is not working by log files or debug code.
2. You can copy file "Data.php" from "app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Helper/" and upload in local folder on path "app/code/local/Mage/Payment/Helper/"

Comment: Data.php what i need to paste

Comment: You need to copy it from the file path mentioned in your error.

Comment: @Gem, did you check it?

Comment: Sorry to late reply, now i am getting error like 
Fatal error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on boolean in /home/test/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Payment/Helper/Data.php on line 119

Comment: @Gem You can copy file "Data.php" from "app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Helper/" and upload in local folder on path "app/code/local/Mage/Payment/Helper/"

Comment: I did same what you told, pls see my post error path like => app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Helper, now my error path like  => app/code/local/Mage/Payment/Helper/

Comment: then you need to debug the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111965/discussion-between-gem-and-chirag-rajput).

Comment: As you know i am using paytm & Payubiz, payubiz return Fatal error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on boolean in /home/test/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Observer.php on line 46

Comment: can you post your code of observer?

Comment: Pls check my observer code in chat. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111965/discussion-between-gem-and-chirag-rajput